# Dynamic page content

Tags: 7, nodes

How can I include body content on a dynamically generated page?

The page in question is defined in `hook_menu()`. I have successfully given it a title but I don't know how to give the page text content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just looking for a standard `page callback` for your menu item. To extend the example from the [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) docs slightly:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['abc/def'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
  );
  return $items;
}

function mymodule_abc_view() {
  $text_content = 'Text to print to the page.';

  // You could just return the string itself here, that will also work fine,
  // but it's 'best-practice' to return a render array so other parts of the system
  // can alter the content if they so desire.
  return array(
    '#markup' => $text_content
  );
}
```

Remember to clear Drupal's caches after making the changes to `hook_menu()`, or they won't be picked up.